# Same method between model & controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To practice, I'm trying to create a small web game with Ruby On Rails, however, I need some information in my model and also in my controller.

I explain myself. For example, in my model, I have the following method:

```
def cost(building)
    {
      wood: BUILDING[building]['wood'] * (BUILDING[building]['factor'] ** self.level(building)),
      stone: BUILDING[building]['stone'] * (BUILDING[building]['factor'] ** self.level(building)),
      iron: BUILDING[building]['iron'] * (BUILDING[building]['factor'] ** self.level(building))
    }
  end
```

Then in my view I use the following to display the cost of upgrading the building :

```
<%= @buildings.cost(building[0])[:wood] %>
```

But I also have an "upgrade" button in my view that allows to upgrade this building, except that on the controller side I also need to get the costs of the building but I'm not sure of the right approach.

[EDIT] :
To give more informations :

```
@buildings = @buildings = Building.find_by(kingdom_id: current_kingdom.id) #Inside BuildingsController
```

`building[0]` It is a string in a yaml that corresponds to the name of a building

`level` it recovers the current level of the building for the player

EDIT 2 :
models/building.rb :

```
class Building < ApplicationRecord
  def cost(building)
    {
      wood: BUILDING[building]['wood'] * (BUILDING[building]['factor'] ** self.level(building)),
      stone: BUILDING[building]['stone'] * (BUILDING[building]['factor'] ** self.level(building)),
      iron: BUILDING[building]['iron'] * (BUILDING[building]['factor'] ** self.level(building))
    }
  end

  def consumption(building)
    BUILDING[building]['coal']
  end

  def time(building)
    resources_needed = cost(building)[:wood] + cost(building)[:stone] + cost(building)[:iron]
    time = (resources_needed / (2500 * 4 * SERVER['rate']).to_f * 3600).round

    if time >= 3600
      "#{time / 60 / 60} h #{time % 3600 / 60} min"
    elsif time >= 60
      "#{time / 60} min #{time % 60 } sec"
    else
      "#{time} sec"
    end
  end

  def level(building)
    self[building.to_sym]
  end

  def upgrade?(building, kingdom_resources)
    cost(building)[:wood] <= kingdom_resources[:wood] &&
      cost(building)[:stone] <= kingdom_resources[:stone] &&
      cost(building)[:iron] <= kingdom_resources[:iron]
  end
end
```

buildings_controller.rb :

```
class BuildingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @buildings = Building.find_by(kingdom_id: current_kingdom.id)
    @kingdom_resources = kingdom_resources
    @kingdom_queue = BuildQueue.where(kingdom_id: current_kingdom.id)
  end

  def add_to_queue
    building = params[:building]

    # If we can upgrade
    #   Add building to the queue
  end

  private

  def cost(building)
    {
      wood: BUILDING[building]['wood'] * (BUILDING[building]['factor'] ** self.level(building)),
      stone: BUILDING[building]['stone'] * (BUILDING[building]['factor'] ** self.level(building)),
      iron: BUILDING[building]['iron'] * (BUILDING[building]['factor'] ** self.level(building))
    }
  end

  def building_level(building)
    Building.find_by(kingdom_id: current_kingdom.id)[building.to_sym]
  end

  def time(building)
    resources_needed = cost(building)[:wood] + cost(building)[:stone] + cost(building)[:iron]

    (resources_needed / (2500 * 4 * SERVER['rate']).to_f * 3600).round
  end

  def upgrade?(building)
    cost(building)[:wood] <= kingdom_resources[:wood] &&
      cost(building)[:stone] <= kingdom_resources[:stone] &&
      cost(building)[:iron] <= kingdom_resources[:iron]
  end
end
```

method inside app/controllers/application_controller.rb,
To get the current_kingdom :

```
def current_kingdom
    return nil unless current_user
    return @_kingdom if @_kingdom

    @_kingdom = Kingdom.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
```

And current_user :

```
  def current_user
    return nil if !session[:auth] || !session[:auth]['id']
    return @_user if @_user

    @_user = User.find_by_id(session[:auth]['id'])
  end
```

And current kingdom_resources :

```
def kingdom_resources
    return @kingdom if @kingdom

    @kingdom = {
      wood: current_kingdom.wood,
      stone: current_kingdom.stone,
      iron: current_kingdom.iron,
      coal: current_kingdom.coal,
      food: current_kingdom.food
    }
  end
```

Thank's in advance,
Regards

Comment: Make whatever `building[0]` is a full fledged object: `building[0].cost(:wood)`. We'd need more context to say more: what is `@buildings`? What is `building[0]`? What is `level`? Why is the information about the building stored in a global of another class?

Comment: Hello, I added some information, don't hesitate if necessary :)

Comment: What is the relationship between kingdoms, buildings, players, and the cost of making a building? A kingdom has buildings. The cost depends on the level of the player doing the building?

Comment: `level it recovers the current level of the building for the player` so a building belongs to a kingdom and a player? Or is it that there are *types* of buildings and a player owns a building of a type?

Comment: A player has a kingdom and this kingdom has buildings. The cost of a building depends on its level.
So yes, a building belongs to a kingdom and to a player.
I added a lot of my code, currently it "works" with what I have in the buildings_controller but I think it's not optimal

Answer (score 1):

fA user has a kingdom. A kingdom has buildings. We can set that up simple enough. A kingdom apparently also has build queues and resources.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :kingdom
  has_many :buildings, through: :kingdom
end

create_table :kingdoms do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true

  t.name :string, null: false

  t.wood :integer, null: false
  t.stone :integer, null: false
  t.iron :integer, null: false
  t.coal :integer, null: false
  t.food :integer, null: false
end

class Kingdom < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :buildings
  has_many :build_queues

  def resource(material)
    self[material]
  end
end

class BuildQueue < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :kingdom
  belongs_to :building
end
```

Now you can directly ask a player for its buildings: `current_user.buildings` and a kingdom for its build queues: `kingdom.build_queues`.

If you want to find a building by name: `current_user.buildings.find_by(name: building_name)`.

---

Your Building model is strange. It seems like a single Building object represents all buildings. And information about the cost of a building is stored in a global.

Instead, the information about each building should instead be stored in a table row.

```
create_table :buildings do |t|
  t.belongs_to :kingdom, foreign_key: true

  t.string :name, null: false

  t.cost_wood :integer, null: false
  t.cost_stone :integer, null: false
  t.cost_iron :integer, null: false
  t.consumption_coal :integer, null: false

  t.cost_factor :float, default: 1, null: false
  t.level :integer, default: 1, null: false
end

class Building < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :kingdom
  has_one :player, through :kingdom

  MATERIALS = [:wood, :stone, :iron].freeze

  private def base_cost(material)
    self[:"cost_#{material}"]
  end

  def cost(material)
    base_cost(material) * cost_factor ** level
  end

  def build_cost
    MATERIALS.sum { |m| cost(m) }
  end

  def build_time
    # ActiveSupport::Duration will do the formatting for you.
    ActiveSupport::Duration.build(
      (build_cost / (2500 * 4 * SERVER['rate']).to_f * 3600).round
    )
  end
end
```

Now the BuildingsController can use what's been set up in the models.

```
class BuildingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # A user already has associations to its kingdom and buildings
    # This is so simple there's no need for a current_kingdom in
    # the ApplicationController
    @kingdom = current_user.kingdom
    @buildings = current_user.buildings
  end

  def show
    if params[:id].present?
      @building = current_user.buildings.find_by(id: params[:id])
    else
      @building = current_user.buildings.find_by(name: params[:name])
    end
  end
end
```

If you want to take action that involves multiple models, make a little object to do it. Like queuing a building upgrade.

```
# BuildingUpgradeQueuer.new(
#   building: building,
#   kingdom: kingdom
# ).queue_upgrade
class BuildingUpgradeQueuer
  include ActiveModel::Model

  MATERIALS = [:wood, :stone, :iron].freeze

  attr_accessor :buiding, :kingdom

  def queue_upgrade
    return unless upgrade?

    kingdom.build_queues.create!(building: building)
  end

  def upgrade?
    MATERIALS.all? { |material|
      building.cost(material) <= kingdom.resources(material)
    }
  end
end
```

You could do this in the Building or Kingdom object, but if you do that your models get complex and fat.

Comment: Ideally, I figured that a player could (maybe) have multiple kingdoms, so the buildings are associated with the kingdom and not the player directly.

I do use a basic yaml that defines all the basic values of my buildings etc., is this a bad practice?

Anyway, thanks a lot, it helps me to see more clearly

Comment: @Akerces Regardless of how the data is stored, the basic idea is the same. If you use a YAML file you can't use all of Rails's ActiveRecord machinery for searching and storing and making associations, you'd use ActiveModel. It's odd to have some things stored in the database ad some things stored in a YAML file. Since you're just learning keep it simple and use SQLite to store everything. I'll take out the Postgres parts.

Comment: Thank's a lot ! this help me so much :D